# How do you get the "beta" badge?

Tags: support, badges

According to the [Badges page](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/badges):

> Actively participated in the private
>   beta

Is this site still in private beta? If so, how "active" do you have to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is now in *public* beta.

The private beta phase is the first week of the beta when only those that committed to the proposal (during the commitment phase on Area 51) can access the site.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

This badge requires a certain amount of activity during the one week *private* beta.